# Write files in codeigniter with prefix

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know this is kind of very simple and has many answers but i didn't got my ans so posting this:

I want to create a file and write data to that file.

I have tried this :

```
$data = array
        (
            'SipUserName' =>'',
            'SipAuthName' =>'' ,
            'DisplayName' =>'' ,
            'Password' => '',
            'Domain' => '', 
            'Proxy' => '', 
            'Port' => '', 
            'ServerMode' => ''

        );


        $file =  fopen('./uploads/text.ini','w');

        // Open the file to get existing content
        $current = file_get_contents('./uploads/text.ini');
        // Append a new person to the file
        $current .= implode('', $data);
        // Write the contents back to the file
        file_put_contents('./uploads/text.ini', $current);
```

**2nd Option**

```
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $data = array
        (
            'SipUserName' =>'',
            'SipAuthName' =>'' ,
            'DisplayName' =>'' ,
            'Password' => '',
            'Domain' => '', 
            'Proxy' => '', 
            'Port' => '', 
            'ServerMode' => ''

        );


        $fp = fopen('./uploads/test.ini', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, implode("", $data));

        fclose($fp);
```

**expected output**

```
[INIDetails]

    SipUserName =
    SipAuthName =
    DisplayName = 
    Password = 
    Domain = 
    Proxy = 
    Port = 
    ServerMode=Automatic
```

But doesn't work.

I want to write this array as sting to my file.

Also i want to set a prefix to each new file that i create how do i do this?

Comment: Not working but which error you got?

Comment: `doesn't work` **how**?

Comment: i dont get an erro its just that my file is blank when i open it,

Comment: @KaushaMehta i guess my implode is not working

Comment: Have you tried to put some text directly, and check it is working or not?

Comment: Yes My text works but the array does not.

Comment: if i store implode in variable and the print_r it give me null so my implode is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$data = array(
    'SipUserName' => '',
    'SipAuthName' => '',
    'DisplayName' => '',
    'Password'    => '',
    'Domain'      => '',
    'Proxy'       => '',
    'Port'        => '',
    'ServerMode'  => '');

$file = fopen('uploads/text.ini', 'a+');

$str = implode('', $data);

fwrite($file, "$str\n");
fclose($file);
```

Or you may try below since this is an ini file:

```
$data = array(
    'SipUserName' => '',
    'SipAuthName' => '',
    'DisplayName' => '',
    'Password'    => '',
    'Domain'      => '',
    'Proxy'       => '',
    'Port'        => '',
    'ServerMode'  => '');

$file = fopen('uploads/text.ini', 'a+'); // notice that we use a+ mode. See documentation for clear explanation about writing mode

fwrite($file, "[INIDetails]\n");

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    fwrite($file, "    $key = $value\n");
}

fclose($file);
```

2nd code will write in file:

```
[INIDetails]
    SipUserName = 
    SipAuthName = 
    DisplayName = 
    Password = 
    Domain = 
    Proxy = 
    Port = 
    ServerMode =
```

You should read more about the syntax of [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) so you will know how they works.

Comment: my file is empty, when i do print_r $str i get : string '' (length=0)

Comment: ofcourse because no data is present. add something in the array

Comment: No But i just want to store those elements each in new line SipUsername,Sipauthname etc thier value should be blank

Comment: you mean? you want to store the keys too?

Comment: See i will post how i want to write in my file

Comment: Posted the way i want to my file

Comment: can you tell me how to set the prefix to that file name dynamically?

Comment: @Rajan That is really different question and different topic from this one. you may create another question regarding that and let the community help you.

Comment: Thanks but i found an answer  :)

Comment: can you help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693349/how-write-arrays-name-while-parsing-an-ini-file-in-php

Comment: @Rajan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693349/how-write-arrays-name-while-parsing-an-ini-file-in-php/35737659#35737659