# Write Database values to a .ini file as per the INI parameter using PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fetching some records from database, result of my query returns some values like:

**Domain:**

**Proxy:**

**Port**

**Server_Mode:**

Now I have a ini file which has these parameters whose value will be empty, So when user edits a file for first time I fetch these records from database and i want to put this according to file parameters.

What I mean is the .ini file will be something like this:

```
[INIDetails]
SipUserName = 
Password = 
Domain = 
Proxy = 
Port = 
SipAuthName = 
DisplayName = 
ServerMode =
```

Now I want to put the values from database against each parameter. How do I do this?

In my view I Do :

```
if(empty($file_data))
        {   

            echo form_input($value_param, set_value('$value_param',$pbx_data));
        }
        else
        {
            echo form_input($value_param, set_value($value_param, $parameters[$type][$value_param]),'readonly');
        }
```

Now the result of array from my query is:= **$pbx_params**
And in that array i have `domain,proxy,port,server_mode`. HOw to write thier values to file  ?
 I guess I have to loop through the values from database and check it with .ini parameter if they match then put the value from db of that row

Comment: @golez its not at all duplicate i want to print the db values according to parameters

Comment: I thought your question was *"HOw to write thier values to file ? "* [sic] That question shows exactly how to read an inifile into an array, optionally populate it with values (from a database in your case) and write the inifile back to disk.

Comment: Noo I Know how to write the values to ini file but i want to match the parameter against the value then will write the file accordingly

Comment: So you want to know how to put a value in an array?

Comment: I have an array of values from database, and i have some parameters in the file so i want to put the value from database against that parameter, like from db i will get domain=192.158.50.55",proxy="8080" and in file i will have a parameter called domain= so i want to put that 192.158.50.55 against the domain param

Comment: @GolezTrol how do i check the array's element against the file parameter?

Comment: like $value_param is the parameter from file and $pbx_params is the array i receive from database

Comment: Forget about files and databases. You read the inifile in an array, you read the database values into an array (or normal variables). Then it's just a matter of writing values to the array, and write it back into the file. For the actual merging it doesn't matter where the data came from.